# Is it possible to change ElasticSearch settings at runtime?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want to set ‘http.max_content_length’ at runtime. Is it possible and how one can do it? And if one can do it at runtime can he also change publishing_port/host?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't. As per elasticsearch documentation, **http.max_content_length** is not dynamically updatable. For more details [refer this link.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html).

Changes we do in YAML file will get reflected in node after once you restart the node.

Comment: @duckqueen Please do accept the answer if it resolves your question.